# Calculus Limits Help

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble with an assignment for my calculus course that I really could use some help on. Here is a PDF of what I am having trouble with.

so far I have the following.

I. Domain [0,4] Range [0,2)U(2,4)

II. f(x) = -x + 4

III. A. Basically a line increasing.
     B. Domain (-infinity, infinity) Range (-infinity, infinity)

IV. This is the one I am having issues understanding what it wants me to do.

[Calculus PDF on page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAClZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand what an even function is. By definition, an even function $f(x)$ is function which satisfies 
$$f(-x)=f(x),$$
for all $x$ in the domain. If you use the definition, it's easy to solve IV.

Comment: that's odd not even

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error.